# Знаки препинания в документе

Tags: пунктуация, согласование

Выявлены следующие недостатки:

Не промыты все фильтры очистки. *Фильтры разобрать, прочистить и промыть.*

Запорная арматура на всех стояках забита. *Краны, заменить на новые.*

Система отопления не промыта. *Промыть систему отопления, согласно правил с добавками для очистки труб под давлением.*

Comment: @grizzly Документ, в котором говорится о выявленных недостатках — не инструкция. Возможно, докладная, отчет, экспертое заключение.  Я бы оставил нейтральное "документ".

Comment: @М_Г Да, хорошо, я исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Первое: предложения следует начинать с прописной буквы. Второе: предложение не может оканчиваться двоеточием. Третье: после слов "следующие недостатки" должен идти список недостатков, а не смесь недостатков и способов их устранения. Четвертое: после слова "согласно" должен стоять дательный падеж: согласно *чему*? Поэтому текст должен быть отредактирован. Например, такой вариант.

**Выявлены следующие недостатки: не промыты все фильтры очистки, запорная арматура на всех стояках забита, система отопления не промыта. Для устранения этих недостатков необходимо провести следующие работы: фильтры разобрать, прочистить и промыть; краны заменить на новые; промыть систему отопления согласно правилам, с применением добавок для очистки труб под давлением.**

Примечание. По-моему, "с применением добавок для очистки труб под давлением" — уточняющая конструкция, ее следует отделить запятой.

Comment: Я думаю, здесь предполагалось форматирование некой инструкции в две колонки (автор вопроса пыталась сделать абзацами, но не смогла). Я немного подправил форматирование, обозначив колонку "действий" курсивом.